# Add contents of multiple lists together

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell and I can't seem to figure out what would be an easy task in another language.
My problem: Adding the numbers of multiple list together to form a single list.
Example:

```
addTogether [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,1,1]]
```

shall generate

```
[6,8,10]
```

Any advice ?

Comment: Take a look at `sum`.

Comment: sum adds the content of one list together, but I want to have the sum of all first elements as the first element, the sum of all second elements as the second element, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a list of numbers, you can make use of [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum):

```
Prelude> sum [1,4,1]
6
Prelude> sum [2,5,1]
8
Prelude> sum [3,6,1]
10
```

You can thus perform a mapping to calculate the sum for each sublist:

```
Prelude> map sum [[1,4,1], [2,5,1], [3,6,1]]
[6,8,10]
```

The only thing that remains is to *transpose* the list of lists, such that we recombine the numbers into lists. We can make use of [**`transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) for that:

```
Prelude> import Data.List(transpose)
Prelude Data.List> transpose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,1,1]]
[[1,4,1],[2,5,1],[3,6,1]]
```

I leave it as an exercise to combine `transpose`, `map` and `sum` to obtain the sum of each column.